# Android WebView doesn't ask geolocation permission

Tags: java, android, webview, geolocation, android-webview

I have an android webview and when it loads page which uses geolocation it doesn't ask the permissions. The webview doesn't show nothing. No alert,nothing! What's the problem? 
Here the code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);

        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();


        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        myWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);

        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);

        myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

            public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
                callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
            }

        });

        webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        myWebView.loadUrl(URL);

    }
```

manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```